# Links not displaying links

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation menu and was wondering why is it when I hovered over the li item containing the link the link does not display?

Here is my Html containing the links

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li class="nav-button" id="home"><a href="Index.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="whatIs1031"><a href="whatIs1031.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="exchange1031"><a href="exchangeRequ.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="typesOfExchange"><a href="typesOfExchange.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="whyCLX"><a href="howToStart.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="howToStart"><a href="whyCLX.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="resources"><a href="resources.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="faq"><a href="fAQs.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="fee"><a href="fees.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="contactUs"><a href="contactUs.html"></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Here is my css which contains a refrences to a sprite which shows each list item.

```
#home, #home, #whatIs1031, #exchange1031, #typesOfExchange, #h-typesOfExchange, #whyCLX, #h-whyCLX, #howToStart, #resources, #h-resources, #faq, #h-faq, #fee, #h-fee, #contactUs, #h-contactUs{
    background: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a634/debuggingfool/nav_zps03a73d67.png) no-repeat;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#home:hover{
    background-position: -222px 0;
}

#home{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#whatIs1031{
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

#whatIs1031:hover{
    background-position: -223px -36px;
}

#exchange1031{
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

#exchange1031:hover{
    background-position: -224px -73px;
}

#typesOfExchange{
    background-position: 0 -111px;
}

#typesOfExchange:hover{
    background-position: -226px -112px;
}

#whyCLX:hover{
    background-position: -227px -150px;
}

#whyCLX{
    background-position: 0 -150px;
}

#howToStart{
    background-position: 0 -190px;
}

#howToStart:hover{
    background-position: -230px -189px;
}

#resources:hover{
    background-position: -230px -226px;
}

#resources{
    background-position: 0 -227px ;
}

#faq{
    background-position: 0 -264px ;
}

#faq:hover{
    background-position: -230px -263px ;
}

#fee{
    background-position: 0 -302px ;
}

#fee:hover{
    background-position: -231px -300px ;
}

#contactUs{
    background-position: 0 -341px ;
}
```

Edit: Here is a demo page on code pen http://codepen.io/Austin-Davis/pen/Fdhej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tag `<a></a>` try put the name of link... xD

```
<a>name of link</a>
```

Or if you like the field without text use the tag `<li>` inside tag `<a>`

```
<a href="www.google.com"><li class="nav-button"></li></a>
```

See this [Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxByH/1/)

Greetings.

Comment: Sweet the style of <a href="www.google.com"><li class="nav-button"></li></a> was exactly what I was looking for. Why is it exactly that this way will render while having the a tag inside the li does not.

Comment: @MG_Bautista, I didn't really look at what you'd written, sorry about the previous comment.

Comment: -1: Ouch. Invalid HTML code, [`li` must be a direct descendant of either `ul`, `ol` or `menu`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element). Most browsers will ignore this, surely, but invalid HTML is still invalid HTML :/.

Comment: I would love to see how your &nbsp technique would work. Zeta

Comment: @DanielFigueroa No problem my friend. greetings.

Comment: @zeta yeah when its displayed after 600px the links disappear and i'm not sure why

Answer (score 3):

Anchor tags (`<a>`) are inline elements. Since they don't have any content they won't get rendered and you have only the background.

Fill them with information (e.g. the actual name of the link instead of a sprite) or use a non-breaking space entity `&nbsp;` **and** `display: block` on your anchor tags. You can also combine both techniques.

Edit: Since you asked about a [concrete example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tDldm):

```
#nav a { display:block; }
```

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav-button" id="home">
        <a href="Index.html">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-button" id="whatIs1031">
        <a href="whatIs1031.html">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

However, I believe this is still not the best solution. I would come up with something lie this:

```
#nav a {
    display: block; 
    padding-left: 15px; /* adjust this value to your image */
    background: url(sprite_a.png) no-repeat;  /* off-image */
}
#nav a:hover{
    background: url(sprite_b.png) no-repeat;  /* on-image */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="whatis1031.html">What is a 1031 exchange?</a></li>
  <li><a href="exchangeRequ.html">1031 Exchange Requirements</a></li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: could you provide an example on how to use &nbsp since I tried  <li class="nav-button" id="home"<a href="Index.html">&nbsp;</a></li> and applied display block with #nav>a{
    display: block; and the result is still the same
}

Comment: @AustinDavis: `#nav > a` is wrong, since `a` is not a direct descendant. Have you tried `#nav > li > a` or `#nav a`?

Comment: Ya just made the edit to #nav > li > a and #nav a still nothing :(

Comment: Yes and it was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

First of all your links have no css styling and no content and thus have no size, only your list elements have size. For the links to have the styling applied to them it should look like this:

```
<li class="nav-button"><a id="fee" href="fees.html"></a></li>
```

To the question of nothing showing the image, that works absolutely fine for me. Except for the last item which is referenced wrong in the css:

```
#h-contactUs
```

should be:

```
#contactUs;
```

Comment: +1 for spotting a mistake thanks. I still cleaning up my mess of having 2 seperate classes for both states of hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="nav">

    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="Index.html">Index</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="whatIs1031.html">whatIs1031</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="exchangeRequ.html">exchange1031</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="typesOfExchange.html">typesOfExchange</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="howToStart.html">howToStart</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="whyCLX.html">whyCLX</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="resources.html">resources</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="fAQs.html">faq</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="fees.html">fee</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button"> <a href="contactUs.html">contactUs</a></li>

</ul>
```

This allows you to hover over, click and be sent over to the 'href' link the specified button has been linked to.