# html links not clickable

Tags: html, href

I've been doing basic html coding for awhile, but I am coming across something here that has me stumped. Look at the page at on http://www.uwfantasyfootballleague.com/teams/2013_Atlanta.html and the page source code. On the resulting page, on the two rows of links at the top, the links on the right half of the page, the CL & PCC, and from SD to the right on the second row, are unclickable.

Here's a segment of the code:

> Edit: well it won't let me post that section of the code because it
>   says I need 10 reputation to most more than two links -- but the code
>   is there on the page

There is nothing different about the code from the ones that aren't clickable, and there's no reason this should be the case, at least that I can see, or there is something obvious that I am overlooking. I can't figure it out. I've looked on different computers, on PCs and a Mac, and from different locations, it's nothing on the browsers end, it's something in the code, or at least how the code is being displayed.

I searched for an existing answer, only one I found...

[Links not displaying links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247705/links-not-displaying-links)

...it referred to "div" and "p" tags, which I haven't used in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CL & PCC are clickable in my browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what you are talking about and I noticed that aside from the links on the right being un-clickable, the right edges of the EA and NYS links are un-clickable as well. This tells me that there is an element sitting on top of your text.

I inspected your code using Firebug on Firefox and am seeing this code hovering right over those links:

```
<iframe width="undefined" scrolling="no" height="undefined" frameborder="0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;" name="aswift_0" id="aswift_0" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){w.location.replace(h)}}" allowtransparency="true" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

This code needs to be omitted or fixed to solve your problem I believe.

Comment: Well I couldn't see any iframe in the code (either in my file or in view source) so I guess it was something put in there from the Google Adsense code, which I now realize wasn't showing up on the page... hmmm, that makes sense.  I removed Google AdSense here and the problem was solved.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

An iframe with the id `#aswift_0` is blocking the menu. Try removing this if it is not needed.